# How does this question have 17K views?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I was looking through unanswered questions with the installshield tag, and came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883956/how-to-use-installshield-le2013-upgrade-overwrite-the-last-version).  It was asked 3 months ago.  While other questions in this list have a couple dozen views, this one has over 17K views.  It seems very unlikely that this number is correct.

Comment: Usual explanation: many people on the Internet have the same question and search for it. Why do you think this is unlikely?

Comment: It just seems like another lower-interest question about installshield, and I didn't see anything special about it that would attract so much attention.

Comment: I would assume the "How to" would attract a lot of views by itself

Comment: I'll have to remember to add "How to" to all of my questions :)

Comment: 3 months and *only* 17k views? pshaw... [Write a program that makes 2 + 2 = 5](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28786/write-a-program-that-makes-2-2-5) on code golf is 5 months old and has 144k views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone posted a link to it somewhere, and a lot of people followed it.

Comment: I see the OP has a website with links to his questions.  So that's how you get the gold badge for a famous question :-)

Comment: @Jeff FWIW question asker is [Announcer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer?userid=2738908), [Booster](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/261/booster?userid=2738908) and [Publicist](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/262/publicist?userid=2738908)

Comment: @gnat Not bad for asking a total of 4 questions!